# Question About Icons and GUI For Notepad++ Lovers

Tags: user-interface, editor, icons, notepad++, ico

In the notepad++ website there's a technique to change the icons with any other "ico" format image. Each icon has it special name in order to be detected by notepad++. For instance, the new file icon is: new_normal.ico. The open file icon is: fileopen_normal.ico and so on. But I can't find the special names for Synchronize Vertical Scrolling, Synchronize Horizontal Scrolling and Run a Macro Multiples Times (I can't even find them in the notepad++ homepage). Well basically I'm hoping that some notepad++ developer would see this question and tell me what are the name of those icons. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not email a notepad++ member? It's open source and on [Sourceforge.](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

They have both a forum and mailing list.

Comment: @alexchenco - if you found out how, please do tell